# How to set and use router in Vuex with Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, action, vuex, router, nuxt.js

I have searched everywhere, but couldn't find the solution that match my use case. I want to make an API call with a dynamic URL based on the information that is typed into the address bar.

I'm doing this with an action:

```
export const actions = {
  loadAPIData({ commit }) {
    Axios.get(
      "apiUrl.com" +
        this.router.push({
          city: this.router.params.city,
          company: this.router.params.company,
          dealSlug: this.router.params.dealSlug
        }) +
        "/" +
        this.router.params.company +
        "/" +
        this.router.params.dealSlug +
        "/"
    )
      .then(r => r.data)
      .then(dealDetails => {
        commit("SET_API_DATA", dealDetails);
      });
  }
};
```

SET_API_DATA commits:

```
export const mutations = {
  SET_API_DATA(state, dealDetails) {
    state.dealDetails = dealDetails;
    for (
      let persons = 2;
      persons <= state.dealDetails.max_vouchers_per_person;
      persons++
    ) {
      state.amountOfPeopleArr.push({
        value: persons,
        text: persons + " personen"
      });
    }
  }
};
```

and then I want to get data out of the API which matches the typed url, such as: apiUrl.com/Amsterdam/Pizza/get-a-pizza-for-5-dollar.

How can I import router into Vuex with Nuxt and how can I achieve the behavior that I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to do is check, that your folder structure is properly made to have that number of params. Look to the docs for that => https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing

Next you can pass your route params as an argument in your dispatch method:

```
  asyncData({ store, params }) {
    store.dispatch('loadAPIData', {
      city: params.city,
      company: params.company,
      dealSlug: params.dealSlug
    })
  },
```

And in your store take the payload in a second parameter:

```
export const actions = {
  loadAPIData({ commit }, {city, company, dealSlug}) {
    ...
  }
}
```

You can read more about Vuex payload here => https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions

Comment: This has solved my problem! Thank you so much mate!